# Threejs TorusGeometry Group error : THREE.Object3D

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I would like to put a SphereGeometry on a [TorusGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry) with [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group)

I use Reactjs so I create a component **orbtit.js**

```js
/** ******** Imports ********* */
import { PureComponent } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'

export class Orbit extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const { scene } = this.props
    const {
      x, y, z, r
    } = this.props

    this.scene = scene

    // orbit
    this.orbit = new THREE.TorusGeometry(200, 1.1, 6.3, 24)

    // satellite
    this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(r, 32, 32)
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material)
    this.sphere.position.set(x, y, z)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.group = new THREE.Group()
    this.group.add(this.orbit)
    this.group.add(this.sphere)
    this.scene.add(this.group)
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

And I import this component on my index.js `<Orbit scene={this.scene} />`

I have an error :
`THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D`

I search on StackOverflow but I don't find an answer to my question.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `group.add()` you have to make sure you're passing an `Object3D` as parameter, [as outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.add). What you're doing right now is passing a `TorusGeometry`, so the library is complaining that it's "not an instance of THREE.Object3D".

You need to use your torus geometry to create a `Mesh`, and then use that mesh to add to the group (just like you're doing with `this.sphere`), as follows:

```
const torusGeom = new THREE.TorusGeometry(200, 1.1, 6.3, 24);
const torusMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
this.orbit = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeom, torusMat);

//...


componentWillMount() {
    this.group = new THREE.Group();
    this.group.add(this.orbit);

    //...
}
```